# Extras for USB_STATE broadcast

Tags: android, usb

I am occasionally seeing the `android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE` broadcast being mentioned, supposedly carrying some USB state information.

It does not appear to be part of the official Android API. Is there any documentation on it, specifically a list of extras supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [platform_frameworks_base/core/java/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.java):

The constant is tagged with `@UnsupportedAppUsage`, indicating it is not meant to be exposed to/used by apps. This probably means it is not guaranteed to be stable across versions.

Also, the intent appears to indicate the state of the USB link to the host, not the USB OTG state.

The javadoc for `UsbManager` says:

> This class allows you to access the state of USB and communicate with USB devices. Currently only host mode is supported in the public API.

And for `ACTION_USB_STATE`:

> Broadcast Action:  A sticky broadcast for USB state change events when in device mode.
>
> This is a sticky broadcast for clients that includes USB connected/disconnected state,
>
> - `"connected"` boolean indicating whether USB is connected or disconnected.
> - `"host_connected"` boolean indicating whether USB is connected or disconnected as host.
> - `"configured"` boolean indicating whether USB is configured. currently zero if not configured, one for configured.
> - `"adb"` boolean extra indicating whether the adb function is enabled
> - `"rndis"` boolean extra indicating whether the RNDIS ethernet function is enabled
> - `"mtp"` boolean extra indicating whether the MTP function is enabled
> - `USB_FUNCTION_PTP` boolean extra indicating whether the PTP function is enabled
> - `"ptp"` boolean extra indicating whether the accessory function is enabled
> - `"audio_source"` boolean extra indicating whether the audio source function is enabled
> - `"midi"` boolean extra indicating whether the MIDI function is enabled
>
> If the sticky intent has not been found, that indicates USB is disconnected, USB is not configued, MTP function is enabled, and all the other functions are disabled.

Comment: The recent iteration of **UsbManager** now declares **UsbManager.ACTION_USB_STATE** as `{@hide} @SystemApi`.