# USB statuse change is detected but I can't detect if it is connected or disconnected

Tags: java, android, usb

I use this code to detect when a device is connected via USB or is disconnected:

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE");
    context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE")) {
                //Check if change in USB state
                if (intent.getExtras().getBoolean("connected")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "connect USB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Disconnect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }, filter);
```

but when I connect to digital piano keyboard and then disconnect, both of them shows me "Disconnect!"
What is wrong?

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55013425/8681), that API is not officially supported

Comment: @Jorn But I test it in API 33